# Libgdx 1.0.0 stage fullscreen android

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to set my libgdx game to use a certain resolution on all android devices regardless of the devices native resolution.

to be specific my device has a resolution of 720x1280 and I want to use a resolution of 480x800.

On devices where the aspect ratio is different I don't mind how this is resolved.

My current code is

```
Camera cam = new OrthographicCamera(480,800);
view = new StretchViewport(480, 800, cam);
stage = new Stage();
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

but all this seems to do is give me a 480x800 area in the bottom left corner (in which everything renders correctly)! How do I get libgdx to stretch this area to the whole of the devices screen?

Comment: Hi there, I realised that the line
    stage = new Stage();
should read
    stage = new Stage(view);
with this change and the one below it now seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the `glViewport` yourself, but let the `Viewport` do that for you.

You need the following code snippet in your `resize()` method.

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    view.update(width, height);
}
```